# Find a basis of a subspace spanned by matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

$G = \langle \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\\ \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\\ \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}2&-3\\1&1\\ \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}4&-1\\3&2\\ \end{bmatrix}$

First I write all the matrices as vectors:

$M_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1 \end{bmatrix}$

$M_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

$M_3 = \begin{bmatrix}2\\-3\\1\\1 \end{bmatrix}$

$M_4 = \begin{bmatrix}4\\-1\\3\\2 \end{bmatrix}$

Then I found the rref:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\2 & -3 & 1 & 1\\4 & -1 & 3 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \rightarrow (...) \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & \frac{4}{5} & 0\\0 & 1 & \frac{1}{5} & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

The basis I get is

$$(\begin{bmatrix}1 &0\\4/5&0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 &1\\\frac{1}{5}&0 \end{bmatrix}),\begin{bmatrix}0 &0\\0&1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Is this correct? It doesn't even come close to the solution in my book which is

$$(\begin{bmatrix}1 &1\\1&1 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1 &1\\1&0 \end{bmatrix}),\begin{bmatrix}2 &-3\\1&1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: At a glance, yes, it appears correct.  Recall that for any nontrivial subspace over an infinite field there are infinitely many different valid choices for bases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution isn’t wrong per se. There’s an infinite number of them. It looks like you were meant to pick out a subset of the original four matrices that form a basis, which you can do by assembling those same flattened vectors into as columns instead of rows. After row-reduction, you can pick out the original vectors that correspond to pivot columns in the reduced matrix.

Comment: "It looks like you were *meant to pick out a subset of the original four matrices*..."  That wasn't included in the description of the problem.  It is a common tactic used, and is the tactic employed by the author of the book, but is not implied to be the "intended" solution.

Comment: Interesting, can I use that with polynomials and "normal" vectors too for the same kinds of exercises? I'm looking for a single way of solving these types of exercises.

Comment: @JMoravitz There is no one correct solution, of course, as I already wrote. However, this is an obvious inference to be drawn from the given solution and more importantly explains why it’s different from the OP’s.

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire If you can turn the vectors, whatever they might be, into coordinate tuples, then yes. You can assemble them into a matrix as either rows or columns: the former gives you a “nice” basis for the span, the latter lets you pick you a linearly-independent subset of the original vectors. Both methods are valid, as are other, more direct strategies. Context will usually tell you which to use.

Comment: The former is then ideal when you want to figure out the basis (by adding an a,b,c,d arbitrary vector) and the latter is ideal if you just want a linearly independent basis out of the given vectors. Did I get it right?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire As I noted in my answer to [one of your previous questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3512552/265466), this business of appending an arbitrary vector to the matrix is entirely unnecessary. It just creates more work for you and, importantly, more opportunity for error.

Comment: Sorry; when I said "figure out the basis" what I meant was to define the subspace (as in $F = \{(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}:a=c\}$ for example). I understand what you meant about this being extra work; I fully agree.

Answer (score 2):

Let's check it out.

$$e_1=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ \tfrac{4}{5} & 0 \end{bmatrix} \\ e_2 = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ \tfrac{1}{5} & 0 \end{bmatrix} \\ e_3 = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

We have:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix} = e_1+e_2+e_3 \\ \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} = e_1+e_2 \\ \begin{bmatrix}2 & -3 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix} = 2e_1-3e_2+e_3 \\ \begin{bmatrix}4 & -1 \\ 3 & 2\end{bmatrix} = 4e_1-e_2+2e_3$$

You have three matrices, which is definitely the size of the basis given in the book. Each of the four matrices you were given are in the span of the matrices you found. The three matrices you found are linearly independent. This means the two bases span the same subspace.

Comment: Great, thanks. I was just wondering how they got to that solution

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire how they got to that solution?  Because they were the first three of the four matrices that generated the space described.  In building a maximal linearly independent subset of generating vectors, you can just iterate over the generating vectors including the next if it doesn't cause the set to be dependent, and skipping it otherwise.  You can see the first three are independent but having added the fourth makes it dependent.